# Change the place of the table in the window in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to make a window in tkinter that will show the results of my calculations. It should have a graph and some small tables. I can't arrange them the way I need them. Below is the code for examples. In this case, I show only one graph and one table.

```
import matplotlib
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,30,size=(15, 3)), columns=list('ABC'))
df1['index'] = df1.index

l1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
l2 = [6,7,8,9,10]
l3 = [100,200,300,400,500]

root = tk.Tk()
lf = ttk.Labelframe(root, text='Results')
lf.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nwes', padx=3, pady=3)

fig = Figure(figsize=(10,5), dpi=70)
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

df1.plot(x='index', y=['A', 'B', 'C'], ax=ax)

canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=lf)
canvas.show()
canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(row=0, column=0)

label = ttk.Label(root, text= 'Res_values')
label.config(font=("Courier", 20))
label.place(x = 810, y = 70)

li1 = l1
li2 = l2
li3 = l3
list1 = tk.Listbox(root)       
list2 = tk.Listbox(root)
list3 = tk.Listbox(root)
for item in li1:            
    list1.insert(0,item)

for item in li2:              
    list2.insert(0,item)

for item in li3:
    list3.insert(0,item)

list1.grid(row=0, column=1)                    
list2.grid(row=0, column=2) 
list3.grid(row=0, column=3)

root.mainloop()
```

The result of the code execution looks like this:

[image: pic1]

I would like the table to be placed higher and closer to the graph and the columns become smaller.

Like that

[image: pic2]

Is it possible to do this?

**UPD**   I changed the parts of the code where it is indicated where to place the table

```
label = ttk.Label(root, text= 'Res_values')
label.config(font=("Courier", 20))
label.grid(row=0, column = 1, columnspan=3, sticky='N')
```

And

```
list1.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='E'+'W')                    
list2.grid(row=1, column=2, sticky='E'+'W') 
list3.grid(row=1, column=3, sticky='E'+'W')
```

The result looks like this:

[image: pic3]

Could anyone please explain what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: To respond to your edit, you can change the `rowspan` argument of your `LabelFrame` to 2, so that everything can re-arrange how you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should only use one geometry manager, i.e. just `grid`, not `place` as well as `grid`. This will also ensure, when changing the layout of boxes such as what you want, nothing will overlap.

To 'raise' your list-boxes to the top, you can add `sticky=N` as an argument when you call `grid` on them. This would look like `list1.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=tk.N)`.

To keep your "Res_values" text above the list-boxes, you can add it as the first row (and change the list-boxes to the second row), and make its column-span argument 3, so it centers in the middle (You may have to add `sticky=tk.E+tk.W` here).

Comment: I don't agree with the statement about only using one geometry manager. The sticky part is almost correct. Keep in mind the OP is using `import as tk` so in order for the sticky to work properly you need to do `sticky = tk.N` or my preferred method as it always works no matter how you are importing tkinter `sticky = "n"` .

Comment: @SierraMountainTech, If in this case OP just changed the `sticky` properties of his list-boxes, then they would overlap the `Label` which is using `place`.  It would be much harder to sort this out than just using it with the `grid` manager as well, in line. You are right in regards to importing Tk, updated.

Comment: @SneakyTurtle Thanks for the answer! Could you see the update in question please? I had difficulties.

Comment: In the case of OP's question yes where the label is placed would be an issue however you should be specific as your statement looks like is saying to never mix geometry managers. There are cases where you would want to and the use of pack and grid happen a lot in the same code when you are just throwing a frame into the root window or similar uses for pack.